# Is there any thing to check to solve "Use of undeclared type" problem?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

My framework is stuck in "Use of undeclared type" problem another one's Mac.

It's weird because this framework is linked properly on my sample project to show how to use my framework and even worked on new project.

This problem was just happened on just the one other man's Mac PC.

I checked below things I found.

1. Bundle resource, compile source check.
2. public class check.
3. set all schemes to release when build framework.
4. set build type to Generic iOS Device when build.
5. Uncheck and recheck target Membership of my framework in sample project.

I think there was problem on the problem one's pc but I can imagine what make's this difference. Also, XCode version is lastest 10 both pc.

Is there anything to check about this problem?

Sadly, I don't have another mac os, so I can't reproduce this problem on my hand. I can't see the problem one's PC right now.
Because I should do something anything, I was test with another mac os account anyway and there was no problem.

I always found the solution of framework import problem before here, but this case is too out of my understand so I post this question.

This XCode Swift framework import problem always makes me stressful.
Actually XCode import problem always makes me crazy.

Comment: How did you shared your framework? A good way would be to use a Pod or a Carthage for instance. Or if you do it all manually, you can still create a new session one your march, reproduce exactly all the steps and check with your sample project.

Comment: oh, he just set the target device to simulator...my framework include library which can be used on simulator environment. so, problem solved. thanks anyway.